# One of my tables drops down when I preview in outlook

Tags: html-email

When I am testing my email the "featured speaker" section in the blue area has about 60px worth of extra space above it. So then it appears not lined up with "Call details".

I tried adjusting padding and different formatting but nothing seems to work.

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-bottom:8px; padding-left:30px; padding-top:20px;"><strong> </strong>
        <p style="padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height: 30px; color:#003781; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;"><strong><a href="https://us.allianzgi.com/documents/Investment-Solution-AllianzGI-Convertible-Fund" name="text_product_investment-solution-convertible-fund" style="padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height: 30px; color:#003781; text-decoration:none;" xt="SPCLICK">Looking for equity-like returns with lower volatility?</a></strong></p>
      <strong> </strong></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color: #ffffff;" width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="two-column" style="background-color:#fff; padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;text-align:center;font-size:0; border-bottom:1px solid #e1e1e1;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;color:#333333;" >
          <tr>
            <td width="66%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
              <![endif]-->
              <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:395px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;color:#333333; background-color:#fff;" width="100%">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="inner" style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:30px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:30px;">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="contents" style="border-spacing:0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;color:#333333;width:100%;font-size:14px;text-align:left;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="contents" style="border-spacing:0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;color:#333333;width:100%;font-size:14px;text-align:left;">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                                      <p style="padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height: 24px; color:#4d4d4d; text-align:left;">With qualities of stocks and bonds, convertible securities have historically delivered compelling equity-like returns while buffering against volatility. <a href="https://us.allianzgi.com/en-us/advisors/products-solutions/mutual-funds/allianzgi-convertible-fund-instl-annpx" id="text_product_allianzgi-convertible-fund-instl-annpx2" name="text_product_allianzgi-convertible-fund-instl-annpx" style="padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height: 20px; color:#003781; text-decoration:none;" xt="SPCLICK">AllianzGI Convertible Fund</a> offers the potential to cushion a portfolio when stocks suffer a downturn or enhance returns when they rise.<br />
                                      <br />
                                      <a href="https://us.allianzgi.com/documents/Investment-Solution-AllianzGI-Convertible-Fund" name="text_insight_Investment-Solution-AllianzGI-Convertible-Fund" id="text_insight_Investment-Solution-AllianzGI-Convertible-Fund" style="text-decoration:none; color:#003781;"><span style="margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-
                                      size:16px; line-height: 24px; color:#4d4d4d;"><img src="http://media.allianzinvestors.com/email/thumbs/hfa_icon-download.jpg" alt="arrow" name="arrow" width="15" height="18" id="arrow3" /></span>&nbsp;DOWNLOAD PDF</a></p>
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table></td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
              <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td><td width="33%" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
            <![endif]-->
            <div class="column" style="width:100%;max-width:200px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
              <table style="border-spacing:0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;color:#333333; background-color:#fff;" width="100%">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="inner" style="padding-top:8px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-right:30px;padding-left:0px;">
                      <table class="contents" style="border-spacing:0;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;color:#003781;width:100%;font-size:14px;text-align:left;">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td class="text" style="padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;padding-top:0">
                              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td align="right" style="padding-bottom: 17px; vertical-align: central;"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td style="border:thin solid #e1e1e1; border-spacing: 0;"><a  href="https://us.allianzgi.com/documents/Investment-Solution-AllianzGI-Convertible-Fund" name="image_product_investment-solution-convertible-fund" id="image_product_investment-solution-convertible-fund"  xt="SPCLICK"><img src="http://media.allianzinvestors.com/email/thumbs/image_product_investment-solution-convertible-bond.jpg" alt="image_product_investment-solution-convertible-fund" name="image_product_investment-solution-convertible-fund" width="177" height="220" id="image_product_investment-solution-convertible-fund"  /></a></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table></td>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                              <!-- START BUTTON -->
                              <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <tbody>
                                  <tr>
                                  </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                              <!-- END BUTTON --><!-- START BUTTON --><!-- END BUTTON --></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                
              </div>
              
              <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      <![endif]--></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color:#003781; padding:30px; padding-bottom: 0px;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td style="padding-bottom:8px;"><strong><p style="padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:17px; line-height: 25px; color:#333333; text-decoration:none;"><span style="border-top:none; padding-top:20px ;padding-bottom:8px;"><strong><a href="http://media.allianzinvestors.com/email/iCalendar/Conference_Call_AllianzGI_Convertible_Fund_071819.ics" name="text_add-to-outlook" id="text_add-to-outlook" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height: 30px; color:#fff; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none" xt="SPCLICK">Join us to discuss AllianzGI Convertibles Fund</a></strong></span></p>
      </strong></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding-bottom:0px;"><p style="padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height: 24px; color:#4d4d4d;"><span style="margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height: 24px; color:#fff;"><span style="padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height: 24px; color:#fff; text-align:left;">Dial in to learn how convertible bonds could help you in today’s market environment. <a href="https://us.allianzgi.com/en-us/our-experts/our-experts-details/justin-kass" id="bio_justin-kass2" name="bio_justin-kass" style="padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height: 20px; color:#fff; text-decoration:none;" xt="SPCLICK">Justin Kass</a>, portfolio manager of <a href="https://us.allianzgi.com/en-us/advisors/products-solutions/mutual-funds/allianzgi-convertible-fund-instl-annpx" id="text_product_allianzgi-convertible-fund-instl-annpx3" name="text_product_allianzgi-convertible-fund-instl-annpx" style="padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height: 20px; color:#fff; text-decoration:none;" xt="SPCLICK"><strong>AllianzGI Convertible Fund</strong></a>, will present the unique features of convertible bonds and their timeliness.</span></span></p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#003781;" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>
    <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="298">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border-spacing:0px;">
            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="298">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border-spacing:0px;">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="92%">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="padding:15px 30px 30px 30px; background-color:#003781;">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="82%">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td style="padding-bottom:10px;"><strong> </strong>
                                    <p style="padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; line-height: 24px; color:#fff; text-decoration:none;"><strong>Call details </strong></p>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td style="padding-bottom:0px;">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td style="padding-bottom:10px;">
                                            <p style="padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height: 24px; color:#fff;"><strong>Date: </strong>Thursday, July 18, 2019</p>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td style="padding-bottom:10px;">
                                            <p style="padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height: 24px; color:#fff;"><strong>Time: </strong>4:15 &ndash; 5:00 p.m. ET</p>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td style="padding-bottom:20px;">
                                            <p style="padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height: 24px; color:#fff;"><strong>Dial in: </strong>(800) 786-6705</p>
                                          </td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td style="padding-bottom:0px; text-align:center"><!-- NORMAL BUTTON -->
                                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                            <tbody>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td style="font-family:font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; ">
                                                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="150">
                                                    <tbody>
                                                      <tr>
                                                        <td style="padding:12px 8px; background-color:#4c73a7; text-align:center;"><a href="http://media.allianzinvestors.com/email/iCalendar/Conference_Call_AllianzGI_Convertible_Fund_071819.ics" id="outlook_add_event_conferencecall" name="outlook_add_event_conferencecall" style="color:#fff; padding-top:8px!important; padding-right:12px!important; padding-bottom:8px; padding-left:12px!important;font-family: verdana, geneva, sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:15px; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none;" target="_blank" xt="SPCLICK">Add to outlook</a></td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                  </table>
                                                </td>
                                              </tr>
                                            </tbody>
                                          </table>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="297">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border-spacing:0px;">
          <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="297">
            <tbody>
              <tr style="vertical-align:top">
                <td style="border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; border-spacing:0px; padding-">
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top:15px; padding-right:0px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-left:20px;">
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="99%">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="padding-bottom:10px;">
                                  <p style="padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; line-height: 24px; color:#fff;"><strong>Featured speaker</strong></p>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                          <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="270">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td align="left" style="padding-right:17px; padding-bottom: 30px;" valign="top" width="33%"><a href="https://us.allianzgi.com/en-us/our-experts/our-experts-details/justin-kass" name="image_bio_justin_kass" id="image_bio_justin_kass" style="" xt="SPCLICK"><img alt="Justin Kass" height="81" id="Justin Kass" name="Cont_0" src="https://us.allianzgi.com/-/media/allianzgi/shared/management-profiles/kass-justin/368x368-kass-justin.jpg" width="81" /></a></td>
                                <td align="left" style="padding-right:17px;" valign="top" width="66%">
                                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td style="padding-bottom:3px;"><strong><a href="https://us.allianzgi.com/en-us/our-experts/our-experts-details/justin-kass" id="justin_kass_bio" name="justin_kass_bio" style="padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height: 20px; color:#fff; text-decoration:none;" xt="SPCLICK"> Justin Kass </a></strong></td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td style="padding-bottom:8px;">
                                          <p style="padding:0px; margin:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:21px; color:#fff;">Managing Director, Portfolio Manager<br />
                                          Allianz Global Investors</p>
                                        </td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                  </table>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What supposed to happen is both the left and right columns with the call details should appear lined up next to one another

Comment: Hey, any chance you include more of your code? Preferably the entire template if possible. Unfortunately I can't replicate the issue in Litmus with just the two small sections you've included. This could actually be what is known as the 'Outlook break' issue, where an email of a certain height, will have a random padded block added by Outlook. There is no indication of what causes it and there is no fool proof solution. But if we can see more of your code and replicate the issue, there is potential we can advise you better.